# how to represent classes on a histrogram plot using colours?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a column in the data set which i represented using a pyplot.hist plot. Using grey color for the bins.
There is another column called 'Class' on basis of which i want divide the plot. There are two classes (0 ans 1) in the 'Class' column.
I want to represent the class 0 data with grey color and class 1 data with black color. How can this be done

Following is the plot formation i have tried

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x= subdf['V12']
y= subdf['Class']
plt.figure(figsize=(25,10))
plt.hist(x,bins=100,color='grey')
plt.show()
```

How can this be modified to show the two different classes on the plot?
Or is there any other plot I can use to achieve my motive easily?

Comment: just subset your dataset based on each class and then overlap them together

Comment: Overlap two different histograms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import seborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig=sns.FacetGrid(subdf,hue="Class",height=5,palette=["black", "grey"])
fig.map(sns.distplot,"V12")
fig.add_legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks! it works. But, could you explain what fig.map(sns.distplot,"V12") is actually doing?

Comment: @SubhankarNayak in seaborn distplot is similar as histplot ; 'fig.map(sns.distplot,"V12")' this line create a distplot with column 'V12' of the dataframe and map it into the fig

Comment: Great, any method using which i can rename the legend's labels?

Comment: @SubhankarNayak make a list "mylabels=['test1','test2']" and then pass it into the "fig.add_legend(labels=mylabels)"